# Runtime of double sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

[image]

In this picture, I'm having trouble understanding why sorting sorting the array requires understanding that "Each string comparison takes O(s) time", therefore multiplying the a*log(a) section. Why are string comparisons in non-constant time? I'm having trouble conceptualizing this.

As a follow up, does our approach of multiplying by s similar to why sorting the string requires s*log(s) as opposed to log(s)? Is the additional "s" in "sorting each string is O(s*log(s))" a result of having to compare characters within the string (as opposed to comparing entire strings to each other in the array)? Sorry if this isn't making much sense, but it's somewhat of a confusing topic for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed two things. Sorting a single string of length s takes O(s log s).

For comparing two strings s1,s2, they can be arbitrary large and we cannot fit them in any register to compare them in O(1), therefore we need O(|s1|+|s2|) for comparison time to compare them character by character. In the picture, author supposed the longest string has length at most s.

Answer (score 0):

Given two strings (say bytestrings), each of length `s`, they can be compared in however long it takes to get through the prefix string common to both strings to find the first difference.  For two random strings, the average length of the common prefix `p` is approximately `1/256`, regardless of string length, so a comparison would be `O(1)`.

However, these are *sorted* strings.  If the strings were random to start, after being sorted, they each start with, on average, `s/256` zero bytes that need to be scanned (for this purpose, the chance that they have the same number of zero bytes is negligible, so we don't have to worry about the rest), so that's why comparison of sorted strings ends up being `O(s)`.  (Edited with a correction:  actually, if the string representation can provide the length in constant time, I guess you can use an `O(log s)` binary search to compare sorted strings.)

On the other hand, we're talking about comparing strings in the context of a sort, and it's not totally clear to me that we can assume that the time complexity of comparison operations *taking place in the context of a sort* will necessarily be the product of `O(s)` for each sort multiplied by the expected number of comparisons, since the average similarity of compared strings (as measured by their common prefix) is likely to increase over the course of the sort.

As a result, I suspect it's possible to calculate the time complexity in the size of the strings for a **fixed** number of strings and vice versa using the argument above, but I'm not so convinced the joint time complexity in `s` and `a` holds for all possible ways that `s` and `a` can go to inifinity.

Comment: By the way, this points towards a far more efficient algorithm:  scan each string in time `O(s)` and create a 256-entry table of counts, a very efficient representation of the sorted strings indeed!  These tables take total time `O(a*s)` to build and can then be sorted using constant-time comparisons in total time `O(a log(a))`, so the final time complexity is only `O(a (s + log a))`, unless I missed something...

Comment: You supposed string is a normal string like sequence of normal chars. This is not true.